# How do you calculate $\lim_{z\to0} \frac{\bar{z}^2}{z}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

How do you calculate $\lim_{z\to0} \frac{\bar{z}^2}{z}$?

I tried $$\lim_{z\to0} \frac{\bar{z}^2}{z}=\lim_{\overset{x\to0}{y\to0}}\frac{(x-iy)^2}{x+iy}=\lim_{\overset{x\to0}{y\to0}}\frac{x^2-2xyi-y^2}{x+iy}=\lim_{\overset{x\to0}{y\to0}}\frac{x^2-2xyi-y^2}{x+iy}\cdot\frac{x-iy}{x-iy} \\ \\ =\lim_{\overset{x\to0}{y\to0}}\frac{(x^2-2xyi-y^2)(x-iy)}{x^2+y^2}$$

And that I could not get out, can anyone help me?

Comment: Try it along specific paths, like $z=x$ and $z=y$ to see if the limit even exists first.

Comment: Let $z=\rho e^{i\phi}$. Then...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the modulus of $\dfrac{\bar z^2}{z}$ is $|z|$, the limit is $0$.

Comment: How can I reach this equality?
I tried here and I could not.
Thanks.

Comment: This follows directly from the definition of limit.

Comment: More explicitly $|\bar{z}^{2}/z|=|\bar{z}|^{2}/|z|=|z|^{2}/|z|=|z|$.

Answer (score 1):

**From your calculation :**

$$=\lim_{\overset{x\to0}{y\to0}}\frac{(x^2-2xyi-y^2)(x-iy)}{x^2+y^2}$$

$$=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^3-3xy^2}{x^2+y^2}-i\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{3x^2y-y^3}{x^2+y^2}$$

From here, show that both the limits are **zero** by changing polar form , $x=r\cos \theta$ , $y=r\sin \theta$.

**For the first limit,**

$$\left|\frac{r^3\cos^3\theta-3r^3\cos \theta\sin^2\theta}{r^2}\right|\le 4r<\epsilon$$whenever, $r^2<\epsilon^2/16$ i,e, whenever $|x|<\epsilon/\sqrt 8=\delta(say)$ , and $|y|<\epsilon/\sqrt 8=\delta(say)$.

Similarly the second limit will be zero and hence the given limit will be $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=re^{i\theta}$. Then this equals:

$$\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{(re^{-i\theta})^2}{re^{i\theta}}=\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{r^2e^{-2i\theta}}{re^{i\theta}}=\lim_{r\to 0} r e^{-3i\theta}=0$$

Answer (score 0):

How about
$$
\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{\bar{z}^2}{z} =
\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{\bar{z}^2z^2}{z^3} =
\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{\lvert z\rvert^4}{z^3} = 
\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{\lvert z\rvert^4}{\lvert z \rvert^3 e^{3i\phi(z)}}
= 0
$$